# jQuery odd behavior of collapsible/movable panels with drag/drop within them

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, widget, jquery-ui-sortable

First of all, huge kudos to 'Web Developer Plus' for writing most of the initial code!

I have a list of 'items' which I can drag into any one of the blue boxes inside the widgets, and then sort them. This works fine. It's only when I start toggling these widgets (showing/hiding), or moving their positions, that things start going weird.

**Example 1**

An item (or items) can be dragged into (and sorted) ok. If I then move Widget 2 above Widget 1 I can't drag anything into Widget 2. I don't get any errors in Firebug. Just nothing happens.

**Example 2**

If I 'hide' the contents of Widget 2, I cannot drag anything into Widget 3, 4 etc (Widget 1 is ok). If I then 'show' Widget 2 again, I can drag into Widget 3, etc but not Widget 2...

My code is here for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/gD94w/4/

Any ideas? Posted another topic regarding this, but hopefully I've worded this better & I might get some help(!). Cheers folks :)

Comment: Bit of an old post, but wouldn't mind bumping it a bit, as it is strange I've not had one reply... :(

Comment: Example 2. actually if you just release the item that you were dragging and start dragging it again it works fine. Its like the drag helper is getting a z-index that causes them to go behind the other elements.

Comment: I tried quite some things, but I think David is right. I've played with the code on jsfiddle but I cant get it to work. When I try to look at the live DOM while dragging and dropping, I do see a difference in the inline CSS. When you move a list item over a moved drop element, the list item doesn't get a z-index added. When the drop element wasn't moved, the list element DOES get a z-index. Besides, a dropped drop element's position is set to relative. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to fix it with both CSS and jQuery. I hope this information helps though...